# Tricky Laravel 6 version situation - Version number unclear

Tags: php, laravel

Right after i run command:

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel MyApp
```

in command prompt i see this message: **Installing laravel/laravel (v6.4.0)**

Here is what i see after installation.

File: **MyApp\ composer.json**

```
    "require": {
    "php": "^7.2",
    "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
    "laravel/framework": "^6.2",...
```

File: **MyApp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\ Application.php**

```
    * The Laravel framework version.
    *
    * @var string
    */
    const VERSION = '6.5.1';
```

So, how can i know what version of Laravel (exactly) i have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add to @Giovanni S's answer, as well as you knowing what version of Laravel you are using it may also be good to know why the numbers are different.

The line `Installing laravel/laravel (v6.4.0)` refers to the new Laravel project template, which gets updated whenever a new userland file or configuration option needs to be added but is not necassarily the same version as the underlying Laravel framework. Laravel/Laravel is the project template and laravel/framework is the actual framework itself

`"laravel/framework": "^6.2",` In your composer.json file is a version contraint, the `^6.2` translates to Version 6.x where X can be any version number higher than 2, but it must always be a version of Laravel 6.

`const VERSION = '6.5.1';` is the actual version of your currently installed framework and, as Giovanni said, can also be printed out using `php artisan --version`

Answer (score 2):

You can get the version installed by running:

`$ php artisan --version`

Comment: Running `php artisan --version` gave me **"Laravel Framework 6.5.1"**.

Comment: Any ideas why it says: `"laravel/framework": "^6.2"` in **composer.json**?

Comment: @Vadim That just means you've set a requirement of the `6.x` series at least `6.2` or higher. 6.5 fulfills that requirement.